# a worker gets killed that has delayed data in dask distributed

Tags: pandas, client, dask, distributed, worker

I have problem debugging the error I got from dask distributed.
I am using loc to take out small dataframe from large ~100M rows and converting to daskArray.
only when I want to grab the data from the cluster I ran into this issue.

> *See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   errors=errors,*
>   *
>   Finally when my data is ready to be taken out with
>   ddf2local=client.gather(chunkDelayedDB.result())

*
The worker contains data that will die and I get following message. In one machine with 32 gb it works fine

File "/home/yousef/pipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 244, in _result
    result = await self.client._gather([self])

File "/home/yousef/pipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1761, in _gather
    response = await future

File "/home/yousef/pipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1813, in _gather_remote
    response = await self.scheduler.gather(keys=keys)

File "/home/yousef/pipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 748, in send_recv_from_rpc
    result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)

File "/home/yousef/pipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 547, in send_recv
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/admin/mypy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 403, in handle_comm

File "/home/admin/mypy36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 2561, in gather

KeyError: 'delayedDB-42a099cc4ddd139877f60c67295ab09a'
I trackdown the memory of the worker being killed at is fine untill getting the data (also it had alot of data.)

I would acknowledge any support that might help so greatly.

Comment: I get this error when I run my program in client. line 224, in result
    raise result
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: delayedDB-fc7a4aba4904137b9a6b219ac3fa480e

Comment: more interesting what I found the error is due to client.gather(chunkDelayedDB.result())

Comment: If you think that you have found a bug then I encourage you to create a minimal reproducible example and then file an issue.